# Toast.makeText() displaying error

Tags: android

i am trying to find location using gps but the following code of snippet creating problem. The error is displaying as

> The method makeText(Context, CharSequence, int) in the type Toast is not applicable
>          for the arguments (GeocodingMainActivity, String, int)

..........

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     String format = String.format( "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
    String message = format;
     Toast.makeText(GeocodingMainActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) 
 {Toast.makeText(GeocodingMainActivity.this, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
     Toast.makeText(GeocodingMainActivity.this,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
     Toast.makeText(GeocodingMainActivity.this,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```

Comment: is this GeocodingMainActivity class an Activity or non Activity class ?

Answer (score 6):

Try this...

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
     Toast.makeText(MyAndroidAppActivity.this,"String!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String address=locationText.getText() + "\n"+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0)+", "+
                        addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(1)+", "+addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(2);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),address,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your MyLocationListener with below code. and pass context when you use your MyLocationListener.

```
private class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
     private Activity mContext;
     public MyLocationListener(Activity context) {    
        this.mContext = context;
 }
 public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
     String format = String.format( "New Location \n Longitude: %1$s \n Latitude: %2$s", location.getLongitude(), location.getLatitude());
     String message = format;
     Toast.makeText(mContext, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) 
 {
      Toast.makeText(mContext, "Provider status changed",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
     Toast.makeText(mContext,"Provider disabled by the user. GPS turned off",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }

 public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
     Toast.makeText(mContext,"Provider enabled by the user. GPS turned on",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 }
```